# How to pull out data from MongoDB docs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with NodeJs and I'm trying to pull out parts of documents so I can use it in my application. I would like to do all this directly in mongo but am not sure if its possible at all. I have this structure with bunch of documents:

```
{ _id:something1,
 firstName: somefirstname,
 gyms: [{ name: "somename1",
          address: "somewhere1"},
        { name: "somename2",
          address: "somewhere2"}]
},
{ _id:something2,
 firstName: somefirstname,
 gyms: [{ name: "somename3",
          address: "somewhere3"},
        { name: "somename4",
          address: "somewhere4"}]
},
{ _id:something3,
 firstName: somefirstname,
 gyms: [{ name: "somename5",
          address: "somewhere5"},
        { name: "somename6",
          address: "somewhere6"}]
}
```

Is it at all possible to pull out data somehow so I would end up with structure like this below?

```
[{ id: soemthing1,
  name: "somename1",
  address: "somewhere1"},
{ id: soemthing1,
  name: "somename2",
  address: "somewhere2"},

{ id: soemthing2,
  name: "somename3",
  address: "somewhere3"},
{ id: soemthing2,
  name: "somename4",
  address: "somewhere4"},

{ id: soemthing3,
  name: "somename5",
  address: "somewhere5"},
{ id: soemthing3,
  name: "somename6",
  address: "somewhere6"}]
```

Comment: my apologies, been away.. your solution worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB aggregation framework there is operator [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$gyms"},
    {$project: { 
        _id: 0, 
        id : '$_id' ,  
        firstName: 1, 
        name: '$gyms.name', 
        address: '$gyms.address'
     }} 
])
```

Example result http://prntscr.com/5crtqm